# Play wav with mediaplayer on android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I try to play a wav file streaming from the web.

```
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("SoundPlayerService", "Error preparing music");
                    }

                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            Log.d(Tag, "Audio is playing from: " + url);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
```

But it does not playing anything. What's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` instead `mediaPlayer.prepare()`